# Sorting in AG-GRID angular for rows with similar values

Tags: ag-grid

Can someone please let me know the logic that ag-grid uses while sorting columns.
Lets say I have a column 'Color' in ag-grid with 3 rows having same values as red.
In what order would these rows get sort.

Does it use this kind of logic, but on ag-grid it looks different.

```
rows.sort((row1, row2) =>
          {
            if (row1.Color < row2.Color) {
              return 1;
            }
            if (row1.Color > row1.Color) {
              return -1;
            }
            return 0;
          });
```

Appreciate for any kind of help.